# How to do mark-like mapping in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

The `m` normal command accepts a letter just after it to set a "letter" mark.

I would like to create a similar command that works across tabs... But my problem is with the binding : Is there a simple way to bind for example `M<letter>` to a function or a command or should I manually repeat all the possibilities ?

Comment: Can you explain "that works across tabs"?

Comment: no because this is not the point. The question is only about the binding

Comment: The LHS of a mapping is not dynamic so you have to create all the possible mappings. If you don't want to have 26 lines, use a loop. Also, try uppercase marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As romainl has already said, no.

Covering this for good measure (and in case someone else comes along later), you can only practically map upper-case letters. As is outlined in the documentation, lower-case marks are only valid within a single file. Upper-case ones, that the Vim docs calls "file marks", are valid from anywhere. Unless you have some dark magic function to resolve ambiguous file marks, you probably only need a single for loop mapping the upper-case letters, if you're going with the brute-force option.

That said, there are a couple alternatives here as well.

As far as I know, the only "dynamic" bit of a command is a count (or a range, but unless you want to map characters to a number (and handle ranges and other fun stuff:tm:), I don't recommend this approach:

```
" The <C-U> is required for all uses. If you want a function,
" you'd need :<C-U>call YourFunction()<cr>
nnoremap M :<C-U>echom v:count<cr>
```

See also `:h v:count`, which states:

> Note: the <C-U> is required to remove the line range that you get when typing ':' after a count.

You can then run `26M`, decode `v:count` as `Z`, and then do whatever fancy lookup from there.

---

The second alternative, and the one proposed by romainl and by far the most used one in cases like this (source: experience and lots of code browsing), is using a for loop to brute-force map letters:

```
for i in range(char2nr('A'), char2nr('Z'))
    exec 'nnoremap M' . nr2char(i) ':echo "This is where the appropriate function call goes"<cr>'
endfor
```

Which produces all 26 mappings.

---

And the final approach is abusing `getchar()`. This means a single mapping, but at the expense of doing additional processing:

```
func! Func()
    let c = getchar()
    echo c
    " Character processing (the `echo` isn't required) here
endfunc
nnoremap M :call Func()<cr>
```

---

You can decide which works for you, but I strongly suggest preferring option 2, as this gives you map timeouts and clear definitions, and more obvious conflict detection.

Comment: I did my loop in python, and my plugin is finished and works like a charm !
I just need to write the readme before publishing